# Use wordforms or regexp in Sphinx to force a mutilword term to be a "word"

Tags: sphinx

Is there a way to "force" `Sphinx` to index a term such as e.g. `iphone 5` into a single-term? For various reasons I can't search for it as `"iphone 5"` or `iphone near\1 5` I need to search for it as `iphone 5`. Naturally the way Sphinx works this means that it searches for both `iphone` and `5` anywhere in the document when I want it to search for the exact term `iphone 5`. Can I somehow index `iphone 5` into a single-term to make this happen.

I still need to be able to apply wordforms/regexp and other mapping to the term e.g.

`iphone 5>iphone5`

This way if someone searches on iphone5 it will find `iphone 5` and vice-versa. The issue is if I a search is done on `iphone 5` while it will find `iphone5` it will also find `Selling 5 iphone 6Gs` as well whereas if I search on `"iphone 5"` it will not find `iphone5`. So my goal is to make `iphone 5` into a term that does not require `""` to be treated as a phrase without being forced to search as an exact phrase which will break any additional wordform/regexp matching.

Comment: It seems regexp_filter should work find for this. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the configuration of the index? 
If so you can configure the index to be created with the `index_exact_words` option.

From the documentation (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-exact-words) :

12.2.42. index_exact_words

Whether to index the original keywords along with the stemmed/remapped versions. Optional, default is 0 (do not index). Introduced in version 0.9.9-rc1.

When enabled, index_exact_words forces indexer to put the raw keywords in the index along with the stemmed versions. That, in turn, enables exact form operator in the query language to work. This impacts the index size and the indexing time. However, searching performance is not impacted at all.

Example:

index_exact_words = 1
`

Comment: Is the `exact_words` global however?  I don't use `stemming` or `morphology` and in fact do that with custom mapping and regexp so I have more control over searching. But if I use this feature will every single phrase be forced into an exact term? But I'd like to control which words get pushed in as exact (e.g. `iphone 5` and which don't). Lastly does `index_exact_words` mean that any wordforms or regexp_filters applied do not get obeyed?